# Каково происхождение слова дуля?

Tags: этимология

На форуме был выставлен вопрос о фиге, с моей точки зрения, комбинацию из пяти пальцев назвали этим словом из-за схожести с листком-пятилистником, произрастающем на этом древе. Есть синоним этому слову – дуля, происхождение которого менее очевидно. И ещё один вопрос: как, по-вашему мнению, слово «надули», приобрело  смысл обманули?  У меня есть две версии, сходящиеся к одной сути. 1. «На дули тебе!» - говорят в том случае, когда хотят отказать в просьбе. 2. Надули – накачали воздухом, который, в понимании обычного человека, является пустотой. Надули – накачали пустотой, пустыми обещаниями. Большинство комбинаций из пальцев  - это индуистские мудры, может корень этого слова следует искать там?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При чём здесь индуистские мудры?И почему "дуля-происхождение менее очевидно"?

http://www.slova.ru/article/7640.html Дуля - дерево и плод Pyrus communis, его называют также грушей и кукишем: последняя дает плод кругловатый, первая большой и с пережабиной; порода дули; бергамот.
|| Твер.диалект- долгая женская шуба. Ассоциации дуля-фига-шиш-кукиш по внешнему виду.

Надули-надуть- переносное значение складывалось в народной среде под влиянием суеверных представлений о колдовстве. На близком расстоянии порча, по поверьям народа, передавалась через простое дуновение. «В 1676 г. добренская женка Аринка, желая ”испортить“ попадью, обратилась к помощи своей свекрови; последняя научила ее: ”как де попадья пойдет из хором, и ты де пойди ей встречу и молви ей тихонько приговор, и дунь на нее, и ее де отшибет обморок“».

Обдуть в преферанс-заморочить голову, "охмурить", лишить бдительности и разума: «Не бойтесь ничего: нашла туча, да мы ее отдуем; все перемелется, мука будет; а берегитесь одного: пьяниц, да дураков; они, распустя уши, шатаются, да и другим в уши врасплох надувают».

Он продулся-позволил себя обыграть вконец, самым фантастическим образом, т.е. позволил надуть в уши.

Продувная бестия- любого обманет, обведёт, уговорит, надует в уши...

А бывает, что и в прямом смысле надувают для обмана. Вспомните Щукаря, как его цыгане "надули": продали старую клячу, надув через задний проход, а он принял её за молодую. Пока вёл до дома, вся "молодость и упругость"на дороге осталась. Да и сейчас что-то надувают, чтобы вид упругий был и качественный. Так что ассоциации именно с надувательством воздухом - и в прямом, и в переносном смысле.

Comment: А ещё : я знаю словосочетание "дура надутая" , которое означает кандидатку в матери-одиночки . Надутая - здесь в смысле беременная .

Comment: 1) Надулся = обиделся. 2) Дура набитая, а про надутую впервые слышу (правда, почему "набитая", объяснить не могу). 3) Надуть в уши = навешать лапшу на уши. И = простудить уши от ветра 4)Ребёнок надул в постель  5) вздуть = наказать ремнём  6) задуть = погасить свечу  7) продуть - трубопроводную систему воздухом  8) обдуть = освободить изделие от окалины  9) задуть - запустить в работу домну